# Define multiple things on a single selector

Tags: jquery

It's my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class1', function() {
    sth ...
});
```

I wanna add these lines to my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class2', function() {
    some other things ...
});
```

But it seems to be a wrong way to do ... And my IDE (pyCharm) says 'you shouldn't use duplicate jQuery selector'

What Can I Do Know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `.on` calls, as they will act on the same selector:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class1', function() {
    sth ...
}).on('click', '.class2', function() {
    some other things ...
});
```

That will silence *pyCharm* :-)

You could also solve it with one click hander, and make the distinction with an `.is()` call, although that could make your code less readable:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class1, .class2', function() {
    if ($(this).is('.class1')) {
        sth ...
    } else {
        some other things ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing structurally wrong and your IDE is giving false alarms that are more performance oriented than related to code validity

To satisfy the IDE you could cache `$('body')` in a variable or chain multiple `on()`

```
var $body=$('body');

$body.on('click', '.class1', function(){...});
$body.on('click', '.class2', function(){...});
```

Or

```
$('body').on('click', '.class1', function(){...})
         .on('click', '.class2', function(){...});
```

Another approach is to use one click listener for multiple classes and use conditionals inside the handler

```
$('body').on('click', '.class1, .class2', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('class1')){
     // do class 1 stuff
  }else{
   // do class 2 stuff
  }    
});
```